image-to-text model for generating image alt text
I'm building an applet to generate alt text for images.
I was hoping to use transformers.js to load an in-browser model, but the only given model (Xenova/vit-gpt2-image-captioning) doesn't work too well. It's pretty inaccurate.
I've heard the Salesforce BLIP model is great - but I don't see it in the available models list.
Is there a way to use a better image-to-text model with transformers.js?
If not, what are some of the recommended ways to add this functionality to my app?
Thanks!
